# SimpleXMLRPCServer, wxPython and Thread - Howto Stop?

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython, simplexmlrpcserver

Here is an example program that illustrates my problem.  The program starts a wxPython application and starts a SimpleXMLRPCServer in a thread.  This all works fine.  My problem is that I can't shut down the SimpleXMLRPCServer thread because it is blocked on the handle_request() call.  I am developing on a Windows XP machine (I don't know if the same problem occurs on linux).

```
import wx
import SimpleXMLRPCServer
import threading

class myServerFunction(object):
    def result(self):
        return "Hello World"

class serverThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.timeToQuit = threading.Event()
        self.timeToQuit.clear()      

    def stop(self):    
        self.server.server_close()
        self.timeToQuit.set()

    def run(self):
        self.server = SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer( ("localhost", 8000), logRequests=False )
        self.server.register_instance( myServerFunction )
        #self.server.serve_forever()
        while not self.timeToQuit.isSet():
            self.server.get_request()
            self.server.handle_request()

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.serverThread = serverThread()
        self.serverThread.start() 
        wx.EVT_CLOSE(self, self.OnExit)   

    def OnExit(self, event):
        print "Server should turn off!"
        self.serverThread.stop()
        self.Destroy()


app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
frame_1 = MyFrame(None, -1, "")
app.SetTopWindow(frame_1)
frame_1.Show()
app.MainLoop()
app.Exit()
```

From my online research, I can see that killing threads is a troublesome issue.

It seems my options are twisted or processing module... Is there another solution?

Here is one post that I thought was unusually interesting, although i don't think it will help me as I am probably blocked at the socket and not in python:
http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t330554-kill-a-thread-in-python.html

Comment: I did notice this answer before and I tried it, must have done something wrong because it did not work - I will try it again if i don't get a better idea. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502610/running-simplexmlrpcserver-in-separate-thread-and-shutting-down/502956#502956

Answer (score 1):

This works.  Credit goes to the link in my above comment.

```
import wx
import SimpleXMLRPCServer
import threading
import xmlrpclib

class myServerFunction(object):
    def result(self):
        print "myServerFunction"
        return "Hello World"

class serverThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.timeToQuit = threading.Event()
        self.timeToQuit.clear()      

    def stop(self):    
        self.server.server_close()
        self.timeToQuit.set()

    def run(self):
        print "runing"
        self.server = SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer( ("localhost", 8000), logRequests=False )
        self.server.register_instance( myServerFunction() )
        while not self.timeToQuit.isSet():
            self.server.handle_request()

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.serverThread = serverThread()
        self.serverThread.start() 
        wx.EVT_CLOSE(self, self.OnExit)   
        self.server = xmlrpclib.Server( "http://localhost:8000" )

    def OnExit(self, event):
        print "Server should turn off!"
        self.serverThread.stop()
        print self.server.result() # dummy call to unlock the socket deadlock
        self.Destroy()

app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
frame_1 = MyFrame(None, -1, "")
app.SetTopWindow(frame_1)
frame_1.Show()
app.MainLoop()
app.Exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether it is still of interest, but the code works if

```
while not self.timeToQuit.isSet():
    self.server.handle_request()
```

is replaced by

```
try:
    self.server.serve_forever()
except:
    print( "SimpleXMLRPCServer stopped"  )
```

Using these lines self.server.server_close() will raise an error in server_forever() which will exit it and finish the thread.